# What is the maximum number of squares that can fit in a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

The conditions for this are

1. No overlapping
2. The answer can be in decimals (so the number of squares doesn't have to be whole)
3. The radius of the circle and the side length of the square is same

My best guess is π (approximately 22/7) squares.
I get this by dividing the area of the circle by the area of 1 square.

Thanks!

Comment: Start by trying to fit two at the same time?

Comment: If you're allowing fractions of squares, you are not actually putting squares into a circle. You've simply found that the area of the unit circle is pi, which has nothing to do with subdividing the circle into squares.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie So, if that exception was overridden would the answer just be 3?

Comment: It depends on the size of the square. That a circle with radius 1 has greater area than 3 squares of side length 1 doesn't mean you can fit all those shapes inside the circle simultaneously. Consider a narrow, long rectangle with one side of length 2 and one of length 0.1 - not even a single one will fit inside the unit circle despite the fact the circle has over 10x as much area. That one shape has less area than another in no way implies the first can fit inside the second.

Comment: Oh I get it now, my logic was flawed. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Any square of side length $1$ that you try to fit in the circle of radius $1$ will need to include the centre of the circle (and a small neighbourhood around it). This is a simple geometric proof that I will not give here.

The consequence is that you can fit at most one of these squares unless they overlap.

Comment: The idea for the proof is that the centre of the circle must always be located between opposite sides of the square. Doing it twice (once for each pair of sides) shows the result.